# Working with a Date Expression (MS SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Good day everyone.

I'm learning how to write queries in SQL, specifically MS SQL 2012.

One of the examples from the book I'm using asks the following:

"How many days did it take to ship each order?"

The SQL query from my book is:

`SELECT OrderNumber, CAST(ShipDate - OrderDate 
 as INTEGER) AS DaysToShip
FROM Orders`

I type the above query in the query window and press execute but then I get the following error message:

```
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type is invalid for subtract operator.
```

FYI, the field OrderNumber is an Integer field type while ShipDate and OrderDate are Date field types.

Is this not the correct syntax to use for MS SQL 2012?  I'm running this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL doesn't support calculations on dates in that way (some other databases do, for example Oracle and DB2). Use the `datediff` function instead:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, DATEDIFF(day, OrderDate, ShipDate) AS DaysToShip FROM Orders
```

The function is defined as *DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )* and returns *the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.*

Comment: Why the down vote? This answer would give the correct result.